# Installing ubuntu on UEFI system after deleting EFI partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, lenovo

I have a Lenovo G580(20157) laptop that didn't come with any preinstalled OS. I used win 7 until now and gradually upgraded to windows 8 and then to win 10. I also updated my bios drivers. My bios is phoenix secure.

I then wanted to install Ubuntu to replace Windows because I am just sick of it. This is when I encountered the UEFI issue.

I couldn't boot to livecd (either on a bootable disc or bootable USB).

Then I switched off Secure boot. And yet it couldn't boot into live cd (Windows bootable disks work). I even tried removing the hard disk to see whether I could access the boot menu, but no such luck.

The crux of the matter is that I can only get to the boot menu on pressing F12 just before booting. I can't see the UEFI settings in that menu. I heard that F2 should open any such menu, but after hundreds of tries, I couldn't get it.

Now I feel that the EFI partition is the culprit and so wish to delete it and then boot via livecd and then install ubuntu. I have backed up my data , just in case. But I am hesitant about this.

Will deleting the EFI partition help me boot into livecd? Please help me. Please excuse my abrupt and confused problem description without any images. Will post more information if required?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that my laptop is 64-bit and that I was trying to install a 32-bit version

Comment: UEFI partition is not preventing you to boot to USB stick; you have to format your USB in FAT32 (EFI BIOS wouldnt recognize other file system) and the burn your Ubuntu image onto it. and do a fresh install

Comment: @edwardtorvalds By the way, I also used a DVD-ROM.

Comment: Did you try to get to the UEFI settings via the Windows shift-restart, then select the troubleshooting, then select the UEFI Settings?

Comment: @ubfan1 Yes. Selecting the UEFI settings brings up the menu of available disks to boot. That is it. Selecting the usb or dvd doesn't work when either ubuntu or linux mint boot disks are inserted.

Comment: @ubfan1 I must add though, before updating the bios drivers, I could access the F2 menu, not anymore.

Comment: You should tell Lenovo support you are having this problem and also you can't open bios settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used Rufus to solve my problem. I tried it before, but it couldn't create a GPT partition with UEFI settings (and other options failed to make my USB boot). This was because I was using a 32-bit OS. The moment I downloaded a 64-bit OS and used Rufus, the GPT option was enabled. 
Now, I am able to install Ubuntu without any hitches.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get to the unetbootin (or whatever boot disc creator you use) splash screen in order to choose the: try ubuntu, install ubuntu now, etc. on my Lenovo B570 Laptop until I did this process:

1. Format USB to fat32.
2. Create bootable Ubuntu USB with unetbootin, but don't reboot at this point.
3. Open the USB drive and delete the EFI folder.
4. Now reboot to do install.

If you selected USB drive as first boot device in your bios earlier, you shouldn't have to use F12, F2, or delete, you should get the unetbootin splash screen and select, Try Ubuntu, Install Ubuntu, etc...
 Before this process I had to use the F12 as you said but I would always get boot errors (can't remember what). The EFI folder was causing the trouble for me.

Comment: Thanks Jody. I was wondering how you got the EFI folder in the USB after loading the ISO. In fact, my problem is that I couldn't get the EFI folder in my pen drive.